# Prove that a set of vectors is linearly independent if a set of summed vectors is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the set of $m$x$1$ vectors $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is linearly independent set if and only if $\{x_1,x_1+x_2,...,\Sigma^n_{i=1}x_i\}$ is a linearly independent set.

I know that a set of vectors is linearly independent if the only solution to the equation $\Sigma^n_{i=1}\alpha_ix_i=0$ is given by $\alpha_i=0$.

Additionally, if a set of vectors is linearly independent, any nonempty subset of it is also linearly independent. Would I prove this by showing that $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a subset of $\{x_1,x_1+x_2,...,\Sigma^n_{i=1}x_i\}$? If so, how can I prove it is a subset?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please make your definition of linear independence more precise. -- And in general, $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ is not a subse of $\{x_1,x_1+x_2,\ldots\}$

Comment: So, how would @HagenvonEitzen proceed with the solution? (Updated the definition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: A general technique to show $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is linearly independent is to assume $\alpha_1 v_1 + ... + \alpha_n v_n = 0$ for some $\alpha_i$, and then show this implies $\alpha_i = 0$. If we are already given that $\{w_1, ..., w_n\}$ is linearly independent, a way to show this is to transform $\sum \alpha_i v_i$ into an equality $\beta_1 w_1 + ... + \beta_n w_n = 0$ for some $\beta_i$. This will show that the $\beta_i$ are $0$, which should imply that the $\alpha_i$ are $0$.

In your case we get the following equations (one for each direction of the implication):

\begin{align*}
\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + ... + \alpha_n v_n = 0 \\
\beta_1 (v_1) + \beta_2 (v_1 + v_2) + ... + \beta_n (v_1 + ... + v_n) = 0
\end{align*}

So, to proceed with the proof outlined above, you will need to transform one equation into the other. Can you see how to do this?

EDIT: I'll spell out a step-by-step explanation of one direction of the proof.

Assume $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ are linearly independent. This means that whenever $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + ... + \alpha_n v_n = 0
\end{align}
Now, assume that for some $\beta_1, ..., \beta_n \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:
\begin{align}
\tag{2}
\beta_1 (v_1) + \beta_2 (v_1 + v_2) + ... + \beta_n (v_1 + ... + v_n) = 0
\end{align}
We can rearrange the terms in this equality to get:
\begin{align}
(\beta_1 + ... + \beta_n) v_1 + (\beta_2 + ... + \beta_n) v_2 + ... + (\beta_n) v_n = 0
\end{align}
Remark that this is an equation in the same form as equation $(1)$. This means we can conclude that:
\begin{align}
\beta_1 + \beta_2 + ... + \beta_n = 0 \\
\beta_2 + ... + \beta_n = 0 \\
\vdots \\
\beta_n = 0
\end{align}
Working from the bottom up, we can conclude that $\beta_1 = ... = \beta_n = 0$. Thus, we have shown that whenever $\beta_1, ..., \beta_n \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that equation $(2)$ holds, we must have $\beta_1 = ... = \beta_n = 0$. By definition, this means that $\{v_1, v_1 + v_2, ..., \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \}$ is linearly independent.

This shows that by assuming $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ is linearly independent, we can conclude $\{v_1, v_1 + v_2, ..., \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Would we write $/beta_i$ in terms of $/alpha_i$?

Comment: @Michael right, and vice-versa. Their relation should let you prove the result you want.

Comment: To be completely honest, the only way I can find to rewrite it is the following: $\beta_1(\alpha_1v_1) +...+\beta_n(\alpha_n)=0$. However, I do not feel as though this is right

Comment: You can rearrange the second equation to get:
\begin{align*}
(\beta_1 + ... + \beta_n) v_1 + (\beta_2 + ... + \beta_n) v_2 + ... + (\beta_n) v_n = 0
\end{align*}
If you have assumed the $v_i$ are independent, you can conclude each of these coefficients must be zero. Do you see why this lets you conclude each of the $\beta_i$ must be zero?

Comment: Is it because $v_i'v_i=0$ if the set is linearly independent?

Comment: No; I'm not sure what you mean by $v_i'$; if it is another vector, note that in general you can't multiply elements of a vector space.

Comment: See my edit for a detailed explanation

Comment: Thank you for detailed walk-through of one way for the proof. This makes much more sense. I was able to proof the other direction, based on your explanation. I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it is not restrictive to work in the subspace $V$ spanned by $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, which the set is a basis of.

Then the matrix built with the coordinates of the new vectors with respect to this basis is
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
What's the rank of this matrix?

Comment: The rank of this would be $n$, correct? How can I proceed with this fact?